# Add total column to report chart (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a report with a chart showing data in the following way (**this is only an example**).

[image]

I show Products and the sales amount for different days. This I achieved by putting in a category group with the products, a series group with the days and values for the sales amount. This is working well.


Now I would like add a total column for each product and all days:

[image]

I would most like to do this without changing the underlying query.


I cannot get this to work. 
I tried adding a **calculated field** with day sums for each product, but doing this I get a chart bar with these calculated values for every day of a product, which is natural as the days are in the series group. In the example, there would appear three new bars while I need only one. There is further no option to add a "total" to a series group like in tables f.ex.

The chart is based on a dataset using an mdx query, where products and days are crossjoined on the row axis, while sales amount are put on the columns.

Comment: What does your dataset look like? (Adding a calculated field to the SSRS data set wouldn't change the underlying query and may get you what you want.

Comment: not sure what you mean... it is based on an mdx query which returns ints and strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to add a dummy member named "Day Total" on the row axis of the query and fill it with the needed sum values.